# Max throws InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, linq

I Have this query

```
decimal? query = context.History
   .Where(x => x.ItemId == Id
       && x.OtherFilter == IdOtherFilter
       && x.Fecha < Fecha)
   .Select(x => x.Secuencia)
   .Max();
```

I need to perform this query into Linq:

```
select max(Secuencia)
    from History
    where ItemId= 1406 
        and OtherFilter= 3
        and Fecha < '20150922'
        group by OtherFilter
```

I need to get the max Secuencia from a table that match with criteria, it works fine when criteria returns data, but when no data match with criteria, Max() can't materialize throwing an **InvalidOperationException**,

```
The cast to value type 'System.Decimal' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.
```

how to avoid that ?

There is another Linq that I can use ?

are those sentences equivalent? if not What is wrong in my linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the type of the `Secuencia` property is `decimal` and not `decimal?`, you should try adding a cast to `decimal?` so that `Max` will return `null` in the case that there are no values.

```
decimal? query = context.History
   .Where(x => x.ItemId == Id
       && x.OtherFilter == IdOtherFilter
       && x.Fecha < Fecha)
   .Select(x => (decimal?) x.Secuencia)
   .Max();
```

or

```
decimal? query = context.History
   .Where(x => x.ItemId == Id
       && x.OtherFilter == IdOtherFilter
       && x.Fecha < Fecha)
   .Select(x => x.Secuencia)
   .Cast<decimal?>()
   .Max();
```

Comment: Will this resolve the issue, I doubt, since issue for `Max` call is due to `empty list`

Comment: Correct, but the overload for `Nullable<decimal> Max(this IEnumerable<Nullable<decimal>> source)` returns `null` if the enumerable is empty or contains only `null`s. It only throws the `InvalidOperationException` for the non-nullable overload.

Comment: Typecasting just to avoid `InvalidOperation` exception is never a good idea, methods like `DefaultIfEmpty()` are implemented for a reason also provides, much more flexibility to provide a custom Default in place of `default(T)`. Also why it fails for primitive value types is, since 0 is not same as Null, it's a definite value, which they don't want to assign

Comment: Ordinarily I would agree with you, except in this case the OP explicitly wants the result to be `null` rather than some default `decimal` value, 0 or otherwise, in the case that there are no values which meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Make following modification to make it work, add `DefaultIfEmpty()` before `Max()` call, this will take care of empty `list`, also you may specify custom default value like `0.0`, here it would be `null`, since the type selected is a `nullable value type`, check [DefaultIfEmpty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
decimal? query = context.History
   .Where(x => x.ItemId == Id
       && x.OtherFilter == IdOtherFilter
       && x.Fecha < Fecha)
   .Select(x => x.Secuencia)
   .DefaultIfEmpty()
   .Max();
```